# Where to place variables in VBA coding

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2007

Where to place variables in VBA coding?

To select ranges, I generally use other coding.
However, I gave the following code a try, and it has led me to query this with   you.

Below are two blocks of code, one that doesn't work-(`Sub sbRangeUsingLoop_01()`)   and one that works (`Sub sbRangeUsingLoop_02()`)

```
Sub sbRangeUsingLoop_01()  
    ' THIS CODE WAS MEANT TO SELECT RANGE B2(startCell):D2(lastCell) 
    ' -INSTEAD, JUST CELL B2 IS SELECTED   

    Dim colNo As Integer  
    colNo = 2

    Dim startCell As Range
    Set startCell = Cells(2, 2) 'CELL B2

    Dim lastCell As Range
    Set lastCell = Cells(2, colNo)  'lastCell REFERS TO CELL B2 THROUGHOUT 
                     ' WHEN I HOVER CURSOR OVER IT IN STEP THROUGH DEBUG!  
                     ' ...YET colNo GETS INCREMENTED WHEN I HOVER CURSOR OVER
                     ' IT IN STEP THROUGH   DEBUG !

    Do Until Cells(2, colNo).Value = ""
        colNo = colNo + 1
    Loop

    colNo = colNo - 1 'MOVE 1 COL TO LEFT TO LAST NON-BLANK CELL.

    Range(startCell, lastCell).Select   'lastCell REFERS TO CELL B2!!
End Sub
```

The following code snippet works. You will notice that I have had to reposition   the declaration and assignment of the object variable 'lastCell' to get the code to work.

```
Sub sbRangeUsingLoop_02()
    ' SELECTS RANGE B2:D2 AS IT IS MEANT TO.
    Dim colNo As Integer
    colNo = 2

    Dim startCell As Range
    Set startCell = Cells(2, 2) 'CELL B2

    Do Until Cells(2, colNo).Value = ""
        colNo = colNo + 1
    Loop

    colNo = colNo - 1 'MOVE 1 COL TO LEFT TO LAST NON-BLANK CELL D2.

    Dim lastCell As Range
    Set lastCell = Cells(2, colNo)

    Range(startCell, lastCell).Select   'lastCell REFERS TO CELL D2
End Sub
```

My question is why does `Sub sbRangeUsingLoop_01()` not work when the   declarations and assignments of the object variables are placed at the start of the code - which is usual practice?

Why do I have to place the `lastCell` declaration and assingments towards the   end of code for `Sub sbRangeUsingLoop_02()`?

Comment: It helps a lot to get good answers if you carefully format your question.

Comment: I have taken your above comment on board and being new to StackExchange, may I ask how I can more carefully format my question?

Answer (score 1):

You first method does not work because at the time of the assignment, `colNo` has the value 2, so you will always get the cell `B2`.

To get the desired behavior, the assignment must happen when `colNo` has been computed, i.e. *after* the loop.

The declaration can be anywhere before the variable is used for the first time (as long as it is defined in the same scope). However, it usually helps to put the declaration as close to the first use as possible.